# Is assigning proc in constant in ruby wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is defining semi static things in constant ruby wrong? 
In my case, i want to do some api calls, but change the headers regarding the params that are passed in.

```
HeadersBuilder = Proc.new do |config|
  {
    'X-Auth-CLient' => config.client_id,
    'X-Auth-Token'  => config.token,
    'accept'        => 'application/json'
    'content-type'  => 'application/json'
  }
end

def self.connection(config)
 # do some faraday stuffs, we actually dont care about

 faraday_conn.headers = HeadersBuilder.call(config)

 # Still dont care about the rest
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is wrong. Well, not technically, as you have discovered, but practically. There is no advantage here to using a constant over a class method (or separate object), but there are several disadvantages. One being that it's not really constant at all (which is probably enough), but it also is much more difficult to test the constant and the methods that use it than it would be if you had used a more flexible class method. You might even consider never using constants in your Rails code, for these same reasons.

Comment: the proc is constant right? Doing this: H= {}, H="" or H = ->{} is still assigning an object to a constant no?

Comment: Also, feels like this is not complex enough to have it's own class since the logic will never change, but the input will.

Comment: Your example in the comment is not the same as your example in the question. H = call(x) is not necessarily the same as H = call(y). Is there a good reason to use a constant, instead of a class method?

Answer (score 0):

I would sugeest you using separate object which only role is to prepare accurate set of Headings. Let's call it `HttpHeadersFactory`. 
One advantage over your proc, is that name at first explains what it does (what is not achieved with your proc).

Secondly, in case you have more complex logic (some headers are used, but others depending on some conditions do not), it will be easier to compose headers.

Comment: Ok agree for the naming. Would be more obvious if i had renamed it to HttpHeadersFactory or HEADERS_BUILDER. In fact, this should not change much so no need to add extra logic. Point here is that it's something that is semi static. of course i achieve the same with a class or method or other things, but just wonder why this would be wrong, beside poor naming.

Comment: Still not a good idea. You are using Consts which suggest something constant - string, hash, number (...), rather never method (Proc in your case). Additionally as far as I know, calling procs is slower than calling regular methods.